# Source a vimrc from a webpage?

Tags: vimrc, linux, bash

I work with lots of different servers and would like to unify my vimrc across them all. I see that vim has the source command, which I'm assuming works similar to bash. In bash, to source a file from a webpage you go

```
. <(curl -s domain.com)
```

How can I do this with vim? I'm aware that I can instead apply each vim setting by adding an alias like so:

```
alias vim="vim +'colorscheme elflord'"
```

but I'd rather not pass thru all my settings like that. I don't want to have to create a file on the local server I'm on, hence the desire to instead source into the local session. Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you could try this: `$ vim -Nu <(curl url)`

Comment: Wow, this actually worked. So simple too. I'll accept this as an answer as it fits my requirements if you post!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `:h -u`:

```
-u {vimrc}  The file {vimrc} is read for initializations.  Most other
        initializations are skipped; see |initialization|.  This can
        be used to start Vim in a special mode, with special
        mappings and settings.  A shell alias can be used to make
        this easy to use.  For example:  
            alias vimc vim -u ~/.c_vimrc !*
```

So, when you want to start Vim with a custom vimrc, you can use:

```
$ vim -u {custom_vimrc}
```

But starting Vim like this will enable the `'compatible'` option:

```
    Using the "-u" argument has the side effect that the
    'compatible' option will be on by default.  This can have
    unexpected effects.  See |'compatible'|.
```

… which is probably not what you want. To be sure `'compatible'` is disabled, you can add the `-N` argument:

```
$ vim -Nu {custom_vimrc}
```

Finally, if your `{custom_vimrc}` file is not on your local machine but on the web, you can use a [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst), which appears to be:

> a form of redirection where the input or output of a process (some
>   sequence of commands) appear as a temporary file.

One of the possible syntax using process substitution seems to be:

```
$ shell_command <( <LIST> )
```

… where `<LIST>` is a [command list](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/basicgrammar#lists).

You could use this to make the output of the shell command `curl url` appear as a temporary file to `vim -Nu`.
So, maybe you could start Vim from your shell with a command like this:

```
$ vim -Nu <(curl url)
```

For example:

```
$ vim -Nu <(curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tpope/vim-sensible/master/plugin/sensible.vim)
```

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, `source` doesn't let you source anything other than a file.

This function is a little bit dirty but it works:

```
function! GetAndSource(url)

  execute '!curl ' . a:url . ' -o vimrc.vim'
  source vimrc.vim
  execute '!rm vimrc.vim'

endfunction

command! -nargs=1 GS call GetAndSource(<f-args>)
```

```
This function will curl the file, source it and delete it afterwards.

Obviously you can execute each element separately, and it'll work the same.
```

Comment: nice, I just tried tested this with a vimrc from `rawgit.com` - as last I checked - github had ceased providing raw files with correct HTTP headers (i.e. they would only serve the file wrapped in a HTML webpage). But interestingly it seems github have restored their raw file service, e.g. this URL would work with your function https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thoughtbot/dotfiles/master/vimrc

Comment: Would prefer not to create any files, but I'll definitely keep this in mind, thanks!I

Comment: Starting with Vim 9, you can source unnamed buffers and a range of lines in a file/buffer.  You can get the output of curl into a buffer and invoke ":source" without any arguments to source the current buffer.